# Robotium Tests Fail Randomly

Tags: android, user-interface, testing, robotium

I am using Robotium to test the GUI in my Android application. When I run my tests through eclipse they all pass without a hitch, however when I run them through maven the tests seem to fail randomly. The activity screens can sometimes hang before the crash, other times I get the error that the text to be clicked on cannot be found, when I can see it on the emulator. I have `solo.waitForText()` and `solo.waitForActivity()` in all the necessary places and have tried many different code rewrites but I get the same issue every time.

Has anyone else come across this issue with Robotium and found a solution? It is a fantastic framework and allows thorough testing of applications so I would like to use it if at all possible.

Chuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please update Robotium to version 3.4.1. The issue that you are describing has been fixed in the new version.

If your issue still exists in 3.4.1 please file a defect report on:

http://code.google.com/p/robotium/issues/list

Comment: Like 3.4 the tests run perfectly in eclipse with 3.4.1 but I cannot test as there is no maven dependency yet available. Do you have any indication when it will be added to the maven repo? Thanks for your help by the way! Keep up the good work on Robotium :)

Comment: It is available at maven central. Please see the following link: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Crobotium